# Unable to resolve dependency tree but caret requirement should actually be met

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, dependency-management, semantic-versioning

I have a problem with updating npm packages that indicates my lack of understanding `peerDependencies` and / or the `^ caret` version range.

#### State until now:

My project `my-app` has a dependency to a package `awesome-lib` in version `6.1.0`.
It also has a dependency to a package `miracle-lib` in version `3.2.0-alpha.2`.

The package `miracle-lib@3.2.0-alpha.2` has a `peerDependency` to `awesome-lib@^6.1.0` (notice the `^ caret`).

Running `npm install` is running fine. ✓

#### Current situation:

I want to update `awesome-lib` from version `6.1.0` to version `6.2.0-alpha.1` using

```
npm install awesome-lib@6.2.0-alpha.1
```

But this gives the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: awesome-lib@6.2.0-alpha.1
npm ERR! node_modules/awesome-lib
npm ERR!   awesome-lib@"6.2.0-alpha.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer awesome-lib@"^6.1.0" from miracle-lib@3.2.0-alpha.2
npm ERR! node_modules/miracle-lib
npm ERR!   miracle-lib@"3.2.0-alpha.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Now, I wonder why this error is shown. `miracle-lib` needs `awesome-lib@^6.1.0`. I thought `^6.1.0` means: all versions up to the next major version. So when `my-app` now uses `6.2.0-alpha.1` this condition should be met, or am I wrong?